# str.split() returns a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, split, tokenize, attributeerror

I'm having a hard time splitting a string on \n. I'm passing a ~138M-long character string of Japanese into a tokenizer/word tagger and I'm getting the "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'" error.

The name of the tokenizer is MeCab and what it does it takes a string, finds words in it, and then returns a string with the word characteristics (noun, particle, reading, etc.) the words that the tokenizer tags in the string are split by "\n" and so I want to split it into a list using the new lines.

first 25 characters of the string:

```
str_text[:25]
```

output:

```
'このページは以下にある削除依頼の議論を保存したもの'
```

When I split the first 1 million characters using the below code I have no errors, but when I expand it to 10 million I get the error I mentioned above.

Code and output of the first 25 characters:

```
import MeCab

#opening the file containing the long string with Japanese text
file = open('output_text.txt')
str_text = file.read()

#passing string into the MeCab tokenizer/tagger and splitting the long string into a list based on
tagger = MeCab.Tagger()
words = tagger.parse(str_text[:25]).split('\n')[:-2] #last two entries are just some tagger info

for word in words:
    temp_str = word.split('\t')
    print(temp_str)
```

output (the first element is the word and the second element contains information about the word):

```
['この', '連体詞,*,*,*,*,*,この,コノ,コノ']
['ページ', '名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,ページ,ページ,ページ']
['は', '助詞,係助詞,*,*,*,*,は,ハ,ワ']
['以下', '名詞,非自立,副詞可能,*,*,*,以下,イカ,イカ']
['に', '助詞,格助詞,一般,*,*,*,に,ニ,ニ']
['ある', '動詞,自立,*,*,五段・ラ行,基本形,ある,アル,アル']
['削除', '名詞,サ変接続,*,*,*,*,削除,サクジョ,サクジョ']
['依頼', '名詞,サ変接続,*,*,*,*,依頼,イライ,イライ']
['の', '助詞,連体化,*,*,*,*,の,ノ,ノ']
['議論', '名詞,サ変接続,*,*,*,*,議論,ギロン,ギロン']
['を', '助詞,格助詞,一般,*,*,*,を,ヲ,ヲ']
['保存', '名詞,サ変接続,*,*,*,*,保存,ホゾン,ホゾン']
['し', '動詞,自立,*,*,サ変・スル,連用形,する,シ,シ']
['た', '助動詞,*,*,*,特殊・タ,基本形,た,タ,タ']
['もの', '名詞,非自立,一般,*,*,*,もの,モノ,モノ']
```

I replaced all "\n" occurrences in the str_text file so that's not the issue. The string can't really be passed into the tokenizer/tagger by one character as it determines what str is a word based on a long string. The fact that it works on the first 1M characters but fails at 10M tells me that this me be one in a ten million occurrence. I've looked for a solution for a few hours now but can't find anything that would help resolve this. I could potentially pass the string in 1M chunks but it feels wrong losing that much data when there might be a solution somewhere.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

@mrivanlima thank you for fixing the grammar of my post

@Karl Knechtel advise in the comment led to the solution of my problem. Thank you!

For those that are interested, below is the full code that ended up working:

```
%%time

#load the txt file with Japanese characters:
file = open('output_text.txt')
str_text = file.read()

#boundries for the text blocks used in the below for loop
lower = 0
upper = 100000

#dictionary for words and kanji characters
counts_words = dict()
counts_kanji = dict()

word_counter = 0

#tokenizer/tagger
tagger = MeCab.Tagger()

#splits strings into a list, used for words that have more than one character to get individual characters
def splitter(word): 
    return list(word)

#break condition for the loop
condition = 'no'

while True:
    if condition == 'yes':
        break

    #this is for the last block of 100k increments
    elif lower > 133400001:
        #initiate break condition
        condition = 'yes'
        words = tagger.parse(str_text[lower:]).split('\n')[:-2]
        print('Last block, chief!',lower,':',upper)
        lower+=100000
        upper+=100000
        for word in words:
            temp_str = word.split('\t')
            word_counter+=1
            counts_words[temp_str[0]+' '+temp_str[1]] = counts_words.get(temp_str[0]+' '+temp_str[1], 0) + 1
            if len(temp_str[0])>1:
                for i in splitter(temp_str[0]):
                    counts_kanji[i] = counts_kanji.get(i, 0) + 1
                    break
            else:
                counts_kanji[temp_str[0]] = counts_kanji.get(temp_str[0], 0) + 1
                break

    else:
        #pass string 100k long string block into a tokenizer/tagger
        words = tagger.parse(str_text[lower:upper]).split('\n')[:-2]
        
        #increment the lower and upper boundries of the str blocks
        lower+=100000
        upper+=100000
        
        #iterate through each word parsed by the tokenizer
        for word in words:
            temp_str = word.split('\t') #split each word data by tab, [word, info]
            word_counter+=1 #count number of words
            
            #check if the entry exists in the words dict, either add or increment the counts
            counts_words[temp_str[0]+' '+temp_str[1]] = counts_words.get(temp_str[0]+' '+temp_str[1], 0) + 1
            
            #check if the word has more than one character, if yes split it and add each character to the kanji dict
            if len(temp_str[0])>1:
                for i in splitter(temp_str[0]):
                    #check if the entry exists in the words dict, either add or increment the counts
                    counts_kanji[i] = counts_kanji.get(i, 0) + 1
            else:
                counts_kanji[temp_str[0]] = counts_kanji.get(temp_str[0], 0) + 1
```

output:

```
Last block, chief! 133500000 : 133600000
CPU times: user 3min 7s, sys: 2.83 s, total: 3min 10s
Wall time: 3min 10s
```

Comment: "When I split the first 1 million characters using the below code I have no errors, but when I expand it to 10 million i get the error I mentioned above." Have you tried looking specifically at characters 1 million - 2 million, etc. in blocks? If there's a specific block that seems to cause the problem, you could then narrow it down further, and then check what the actual text is that causes the problem.

Comment: You should put the line that is generating the exception in a try/except block.   In your except block, examine your word variable and verify that it is, in fact, None.  In fact, if you start your loop with `for index, word in enumerated(words):`, you will have an index number for the failing word.

Comment: RufusVS, yeah but it's failing at the words part, sorry I should've been clearer in my explanation. Using Karl's recommendation, I just found that an error is in the 3-4 million block so i guess I will just keep making the blocks/loops smaller until i find the culprit. Thank you, both.

Comment: You could just put it into a `try..except` block and print out what falls into `except`.

Comment: okay, it looks like the tokenizer just does not like string blocks to produce a certain amount of words. The reason the program broke in the block 3-4 million was not because there was some character it did not like there but it's because it produced more words than some other 1 million-character-long blocks. When I split it into 100K-character-blocks everything was processed just fine. I can't seem to break my while loop now, but oh well, I'll figure it out.

@KarlKnechtel Thank you, for your help. Your advise led to the solution. Could you post it as an answer so I can credit you?

Comment: @HélitonMartins how would that work if it's done on the whole string?

Comment: it looks like an issue in MeCab. You could run the failing test in a debugger and inspect the state near the AttributeError

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of mecab-python3.

I think you might have mailed me about this, but please, do not pass MeCab 1M character strings. It was developed with the assumption that the input is a single sentence. It's robust, and it handles much longer strings - you won't have trouble with a paragraph, for example - but you're basically running into untested territory for no benefit.

Split your input text into paragraphs or sentences before passing it to MeCab.

Also, regarding this:

> I could potentially pass the string in 1M chunks but it feels wrong losing that much data when there might be a solution somewhere.

You will not lose any data by passing shorter strings. I'm not sure what you're referring to here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your message! I ended up shortening the strings to 100K character long strings and when examining the output, mecab-python3 seems to have handled it very well. I can try splitting the string on periods to get sentences and see if the output changes.

That paragraph that you quoted was regarding me splitting a 130+ million character string into 1M character strings, and some of those were too long for MeCab and it failed.